# Math calculating with two JSONB keys in Postgres?

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb

I have JSONB column with data like:

```
{"plays": {"win": 90, "draw": 8, "lose": 2}}
```

How I can calculate sum with `win` and `draw` keys?

Something like:

```
SELECT
    data::json#>>'{plays,draw}' + data::json#>>'{plays,win}' as "total_plays",
FROM
    plays_data;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's assume your table and data are the following ones (note that I have avoided called `json` any column, to avoid confusion between column names and types; this is a recommended practice):

```
CREATE TABLE data
(
    some_data json
) ;

INSERT INTO data
    (some_data)
VALUES
    ('{"plays": {"win": 90, "draw": 8, "lose": 2}}') ;
```

You need to use the following query:

```
SELECT
    CAST(some_data->'plays'->>'win' AS INTEGER) + CAST(some_data->'plays'->>'draw' AS INTEGER) AS total_plays
FROM
    data ;
```

```
| total_plays |
| ----------: |
|          98 |
```

Explanation:

1. `->` operator, applied to a JSON column (a JSON object) on the left, and a *string* on the right, gives back the corresponding field as a JSON object (which might be an object, an array or a value).
2. `->>` operator gives back the field *value* as a `text`. PostgreSQL doesn't have a way to know whether your data is a *string*, *number* or *boolean*; it treats everything as *strings*, which is how they're stored.
3. `CAST(expression AS type)` converts the expression to the specified type. JavaScript might use a number or a string and cast from one to the other as needed. PostgreSQL must be told explicitly most of the times whether a certain expressions needs to be interpreted as one or the other. As for *numbers*, JavaScript doesn't let you specify between *floats* or *integers*. PostgreSQL needs to be that specific.

You can check everything at *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=03591871949e8945edf8ac90906d6924)*

---

Reference:

- [PostgreSQL JSON functions and operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html)
- [`CAST`](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-cast/)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
    *, j.draw + j.win as total_plays
FROM
    plays_data,
    json_to_record(data->'plays') as j(win int, draw int, lose int);
```